# would you like to trust the iis express ssl certificate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl

I read tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on.
in paragraph 8 , I accidentally click "no".how to fix it?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing, after having clicked 'No'? Do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: i wanted to click "yes".How to fix it?

Comment: I understand, but _what is the actual problem you are facing right now?_ Are there any actions you are unable to do, because you clicked 'no'? Is anything **preventing** you from continuing?

Comment: untrusted certificate in browser

Comment: Usually, you can chose to continue to the site, despite the untrusted certificate. How to do this depends on your browser. After doing this, you can chose to install / trust the certificate by clicking it in the address bar of the browser.